# webview js interface can not use prototype

Tags: javascript, webview, chromium, v8

I use webview inject a object just like this:

```
public class mediaplayer {

    @JavascriptInterface
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void testInterface(int num) {
        Log.d("mediaplayer","testInterface2...." + num);
    }

}
 public mediaplayer _mediaplayer = new mediaplayer();
 WebView.addJavascriptInterface(_mediaplayer, "IPTVPlayer");
```

---

and i want use it in web page, just like this:

```
function MediaPlayer2()
{

    return IPTVPlayer;
}
MediaPlayer2.prototype.setPlayerParams = function (channel) {

    console.log('MediaPlayer2.prototype.setPlayerParams2................');

};
 var mp2 = new MediaPlayer2(); 
 mp2.setPlayerParams("this is test");
```

---

when i run it ,it come out error:

*TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setPlayerParams'*

---

I must use webview method just like that, so must return *'IPTVPlayer'* .I don't know why i can not use prototype method, please give me some suggestions. I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Prototype-based inheritance without classes can be quite tricky in JavaScript.
There are two main things you have to do:

```
// 1. Correctly set up the constructors to call the super constructor
function MediaPlayer2() {
  // Call the "super" constructor with the new instance (this).
  IPTVPlayer.call(this)
}
// 2. Correctly set up the lookup chain via the prototype
MediaPlayer2.prototype = Object.create(IPTVPlayer.prototype);
MediaPlayer2.prototype.constructor = MediaPlayer2;

// Now you can start adding methods.
MediaPlayer2.prototype.setPlayerParams = ...
```

I suggest to keep on reading a bit more [background work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance) as well and start using ES6 classes which are more explicit:

```
class MediaPlayer2 extends IPTVPlayer {
  constructor() { super(); ... }
  setPlayerParams(...) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your answer. I try just as you said.But it also come out error: Object prototype may only be an Object or null,,, Object [object Object] has no method 'call'.  I think it's because of IPTVPlayer. It is a Object by webview inject, not a function.

Comment: You're right, you inject an instance into the webview instead of a class/constructor function. Either try injecting the class directly from Java (which I'm not fully sure will work), or try extracting the constructor from the passed instance, i.e. `IPTVPlayer..constructor`.